# Custom Post Type Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, custom-post-type

I have read dozens of posts spanning several years. I can not find any step-by-step explanation how-best to create custom post types, custom taxonomies, custom post fields, and then hook to utilize the Woocommerce single-product template for display?

There will be a price but no actual checkout or buy now because I am using the catalog plugin.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.